# Using Metadata Extractor 2.8.0 to get the PictureControlName for Nikon D600?

Tags: .net, metadata-extractor

Using Metadata Extractor 2.8.0 I'm trying to retrieve the value for the `PictureControlName` from the `makernotes` of an image captured with a Nikon D600.  The `makernotes` library seems to only return [58 values].  How do I access the 58 values?

```
var mkNotes = directories.OfType<NikonType2MakernoteDirectory>().FirstOrDefault();
var picCntrl = mkNotes?.GetDescription(NikonType2MakernoteDirectory.TagPictureControl);
```

Comment: This was fixed in https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet/pull/341 and released in [2.8.1](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet/releases/tag/2.8.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the library does not yet support the `PictureControl` data you're after.

Looking at the amazing resource that is ExifTool documentation, we can see how the values might be decoded:

https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Nikon.html#PictureControl

Given you have 58 values, I assume your data's encoded using the first format:

[image]

If you would be up for contributing a PR to the project that decodes that data, I would be happy to provide pointers towards doing so. The short version would be that we'd add new `PictureControlDirectory` and `PictureControlDescriptor` classes, and some code to decode the 58 values into such a directory. It shouldn't be too hard to do this. We don't need unit tests, as we use a large data set to track regressions. If we don't yet have an image containing this data, it'd be great if you could contribute one.

Comment: This was fixed in https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet/pull/341 and released in [2.8.1](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet/releases/tag/2.8.1).